# Doxygen plugin in Jenkins: OUTPUT_DIRECTORY error

Tags: jenkins, doxygen

The root of the my application, where the Doxyfile is located, is:
`/home/aaa/public_html`

I want to generate the documentation in:
`/home/bbb/public_html/ccc`

It works well but not with Jenkins: I get the error `hudson.AbortException: The output directory doesn't exist.`

The workspace of my Jenkins job is:
`/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Doxy1/workspace`

I tried hard but it won't work. What could I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the solution.

Instead of using the plugin, I just created freestyle job in Jenkins with the Doxygen generation command in it.

Comment: But that doesn't actually publish it correct? I get the same error as above

Comment: Well yes it does. Jenkins executes `doxygen path/to/Doxyfile`, and in the Doxyfile I put the destination folder. Then the HTML files are generated in it.

Comment: Yup i actually had it backwards... the plugin only publishes and you have to add a build action to run doxygen yourself... did not know that.

Comment: I have the same issue, have you a solution to "generate" the documentation link on the job page ? Thanks !

Comment: @thanks, it works, but why we need tell doxyfile to doxygen

Answer (score 0):

I've found out that the error `hudson.AbortException: The output directory doesn't exist` refers to the OUTPUT_DIRECTORY variable in the Doxygen configuration file.

You have to take three things into account with the Doxygen plugin (at least as of 0.15).

In the Doxygen plugin configuration in a Jenkins task:

- **Doxyfile path**: this path has to be RELATIVE to the Jenkins task workspace. And point to the .doxy file that contains the Doxygen configuration.
- **Folder from which doxygen is run**: a folder within the Jenkins task workspace.

In the Doxygen configuration file:

- **OUTPUT_DIRECTORY variable**: this variable sets the directory where we want to generate the Doxygen output. It can be relative or absolute. In case it was relative, it would be relative to the folder from which Doxygen is run. If we want to leave the Doxygen output in the same folder from which we run Doxygen, we should leave this OUTPUT_DIRECTORY variable empty.

Comment: The error I'm getting is: "The output directory could not be read from the configuration." I have set OUTPUT_DIRECTORY to both nothing and to '.' and get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Since version 0.16, the Doxygen plugin provides a build step to generate the documentation.

See https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Doxygen+Plugin

Answer (score -1):

I found that I get this error if the `publish doxygen` build step `doxyfile path` field contains extra whitespace.  Make sure that your doxyfile path doesn't have any trailing spaces or other whitespace characters.  My doxygen plugin version is 0.18.